# model not an instance of a model, but has attributes of a particular instance

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, ecmascript-6

The best way to think of the problem is to consider it in terms of the Backbone TodoMVC app (even though that's not what I'm doing, it's similar in that it has one main view and many list views). If you declare a custom `destroy` method on the Todo model (such as one I have below) and click on a view to delete it, then in the method that's triggered (where this.model.destroy is called), you can't invoke the custom destroy method on the model, because `this.model` is not an instance of the model. Somehow calling `this.model.destroy`

```
     clear: function () {    //in the todo app, this method is called clear
        this.model.destroy(); 
    }
```

works to destroy the model but not if you're trying to invoke a custom destroy method.

Below, I explain the same in terms of my app.

I have a Backbone application that uses server side  storage but am unable to send a delete request to the server. Using another SO answer, I created a custom destroy method on the model (`FunkyModel` shown below) and I try to call that custom destroy method in a deleteModel method in the view but to no avail.

However, it's not calling the custom destroy method on FunkyModel.When I inspect `this.model`, it doesn't say it's an instance of `FunkyModel`, rather it only says `Backbone.Model` and then lists the model's properties. So obviously it's not an instance of FunkyModel and therefore not a surprise that it can't call the custom destroy method on FunkyModel, but at the same time under the `attributes` property, it has all the attributes of an instance of FunkyModel.

Question: how can a model have attributes that are unique to an instance of a model but not be an instance of that model, but rather simply Backbone.Model

Further Info:
The application is structured like the BackboneMVC Todo App in that there is one main view and then it attaches more views as list items. When I click on a delete symbol on one of the views, it triggers an event that calls the `deleteModel` method, in which I call

```
 deleteModel(e){
         this.model.destroy();
     }
```

So naturally, depending on which list view I click on, the attributes of this.model will be different, but in no case is it ever an instance of the model. It's simply a Backbone.Model and its attributes have the properties of a particular instance. I'm not sure how a model that's not an instance can have properties in its attributes that are from a particular instance.

**model**

```
  export class FunkyModel extends Model{

     defaults(){
               return {
                      name: '',
                      type: ''
             }

            }

     addToCollection(){
                   collection.add(this);
                   this.save();
         }
      destroy(options){
           var opts = _.extend({url: '/api/'}, options || {});
           console.log("never getting run");
           return Backbone.Model.prototype.destroy.call(this, opts);

       }
     }
```

view

```
 deleteModel(e){
     this.model.destroy({success: function(model, response, xhr){
          console.log(model,xhr, options, "success callback") //xhr is undefined
       },
       error: function(model, xhr,options){ 
           console.log(model,xhr,options, "error callback")
      }
 }
```

Further Info

When the model's created, I do

```
this.model = new FunkyModel();
this.model.set({"type": "funky"})
```

When the model gets saved, it gets added to the collection (code shown above in original OP). I'm wondering if when I call this.model.destroy(), it's only destroying it in terms of removing it from the collection (hence the success callback is fired).

Comment: Did it work if you didn't use ES6?

Comment: @Bergi I don't have my application set up to test that

Comment: Can you debug your app? Is `deleteModel` actually run? What is `this.model`? Are you sure it's an instance of `FunkyModel`?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @AdrianLynch as it says in the OP, the success callback is fired in deleteModel function, but the xhr object in the callback is undefined, which I think validates that a delete request is not made to server. But the model.destroy() call itself is not creating any errrors, it's removing the model from the collection, just not sending the delete request.

Comment: @Bergi deleteModel is definitely run, and yes, `this.model` is an instance of `FunkyModel`

Comment: Then it will run your `destroy` method, unless you've overwritten it on that particular instance. Can you `console.log(this.model.destroy == FunkyModel.prototype.destroy)`? If the answer is true, then either `_.extend()` throws or `console.log("never getting run");` is actually run, if the answer is false please show us how `this.model` was constructed and what it actually is.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the tip. that log statement returns `false`. I have a type field on the model which confirms that it's an instance of FunkyModel. I'll add some more detail in the OP. My suspicion right now is that this.model.destroy is calling a destroy method on the collection only.  Is that possible?

Comment: No, that shouldn't be possible. Can you test whether the `.destroy` property has the expected value right after `this.model = new FunkyModel();`?

Comment: it does have the expected value. If I log `this.model.destroy`, it logs the destroy function code.

Comment: The `this` in the `deleteModel` view function is the same as the `this` where you created the `.model` on? What else does alter the `.model` or `.model.destroy`?

Comment: no, the two "this" are two different views. The view where it's created is a page view that corresponds to a route. The view where I call model.destroy is a view embedded in the route view.

Comment: I misspoke earlier. When I click `this.model.destroy`, this.model is actually not an instance of `FunkyMode`l. It only says `Backbone.Model`, however, all the attributes of this.model are the attributes from FunkyModel. Furthermore, when I log, this.model.destroy, it shows the native destroy method, not the custom destroy method on FunkyModel. So, how can this Backbone.Model's attributes property contain all the properties of FunkyModel but not be an instance of FunkyModel?

Comment: @Bergi it's actually very easy to see my problem if you know the Backbone TodoMVC app. Imagine putting a custom destroy method on the Todo model in that app, and when you click a delete on any of the list views try to invoke that custom destroy. It won't work, for the same reason. `this.model` in the view is not an instance of the model.

Comment: Do you ever create models by passing raw attributes objects to the collection, and, if so, does the collection have a `model` property defined?

Comment: @andrewlarson no and no, regarding latter point, I'm  putting several different kinds of models in the collection, so I didn't think there was a way to declare a model property

Comment: You can define a function that will return the proper type: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model. That said, if you aren't passing POJOs to collection methods that use them to create models, this presumably isn't the problem.

Comment: @andrewlarson are you familiar with the todomvc app?  If I define a custom destroy method on that model, it doesn't get called when this.model.destroy runs in the view., similar to what's happening in my app.Anyways, I didn't realize I could override the model property but I don't think that's the problemm

Comment: I haven't looked at it before, sorry. The behavior here is something I've usually seen from adding POJOs without a model defined on the collection (`fetch` is a common culprit); if that isn't happening, I don't have anything terribly helpful to add.